# Remove Local Links from HTML Text

Tags: regex, vb.net

How can I change this line of code so that i only remove internal links and no external links?

```
txtDesc.Text = Regex.Replace(txtDesc.Text, "</?(a|A).*?>", "")
```

so the string belong

"Click here to go to the <a href="/firstpage">FirstPage</a>."

has the "a href" removed so that the string is just "Click here to go to the FirstPage."  but

"<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a> is great site"

is left as it is.  VB or C# code is ok.

Comment: Based on those examples, you could do this without using regex at all, just check to see if the `href` starts with "http".

Comment: One trick is to check for relative links beginning with slash('/'). Also, post what have you tried so far? It would be helpful to guide you if you let us know where are you stuck.

Comment: please explain what you want to remove clearly. Do you want to remove the string inside `href` or the entire `a` tag?

Comment: [`txtDesc.Text = Regex.Replace(s, "(?i)<a\b[^<]*?\shref="(?!https?://)[^<]*?>([^<]*)</a>", "$1")`](https://regex101.com/r/JhjbMH/1)